# problem with gatsby-plugin-intl and gatsby-plugin-mdx

Tags: internationalization, gatsby, react-intl, gatsby-plugin-mdx

My blog posts are as following:

```
posts
     /post-1
            /en.mdx
            /fr.mdx
```

I created a page for each in `gatsby-node.js` file as following:

```js
...
createPage({
        path: `/${lang}/post/${node.frontmatter.slug}/`,
        component: `${postTemplate}?__contentFilePath=${node.internal.contentFilePath}`,
        context: {
          id: node.id,
          slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
          lang: lang,
        },
      });
...
```

But if I go to url `/fr/post/post-1` (or en), as `gatsby-plugin-intl` creates `/en/...` and `/fr/...`, it redirects it to `/en/en/post/post-1` or `/fr/fr/post/post-1`.

Any solution?